# How to convert svg element coordinates to screen coordinates?

Tags: javascript, svg

Is there a way to get the screen/window coordinates from a svg element ?
I have seen solutions for the other way around like:

```
function transformPoint(screenX, screenY) {
   var p = this.node.createSVGPoint()
    p.x = screenX
    p.y = screenY
    return p.matrixTransform(this.node.getScreenCTM().inverse())
}
```

But what i need in my case are the screen coordinates.

Sory if it's an obvious question, but i'm new to svg.
Thanks.

Comment: What's the goal of this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was playing around with this snippet below when I wanted to do the same (learn which screen coordinates correspond to the SVG coordinates). I think in short this is what you need:

1. Learn current transformation matrix of the SVG element (which coordinates you are interested in), roughly: matrix = element.getCTM();
2. Then get screen position by doing, roughly: position = point.matrixTransform(matrix), where "point" is a SVGPoint.

See the snippet below. I was playing with this by changing browser window size and was altering svg coordinates to match those of the div element

```js
// main SVG:
var rootSVG = document.getElementById("rootSVG");
// SVG element (group with rectangle inside):
var rect = document.getElementById("rect");
// SVGPoint that we create to use transformation methods:
var point = rootSVG.createSVGPoint();
// declare vars we will use below:
var matrix, position;
// this method is called by rootSVG after load:
function init() {
  // first we learn current transform matrix (CTM) of the element' whose screen (not SVG) coordinates we want to learn:
  matrix = rect.getCTM();
  // then we "load" SVG coordinates in question into SVGPoint here:
  point.x = 100;  // replace this with the x co-ordinate of the path segment
  point.y = 300;  // replace this with the y co-ordinate of the path segment
  // now position var will contain screen coordinates:
  position = point.matrixTransform(matrix);
  console.log(position)
  // to validate that the coordinates are correct - take these x,y screen coordinates and apply to CSS #htmlRect to change left, top pixel position. You will see that the HTML div element will get placed into the top left corner of the current svg element position.
}
```

```css
html, body {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border: 0;
 overflow:hidden;
 background-color: #fff; 
}
svg {
      position: fixed; 
   top:0%; 
   left:0%; 
   width:100%; 
   height:100%; 
   background:#fff;   
}
#htmlRect {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background: green;
  position: fixed;
  left: 44px;
  top: 132px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <svg id="rootSVG" width="100%" height="100%" viewbox="0 0 480 800" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" onload="init()">

    <g id="rect">
      <rect id="rectangle" x="100" y="300" width="400" height="150"/>
    </g>

  </svg>
  <div id="htmlRect"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: sorry to avoid your confusion - this is how you use the snippet;) see what it gives you in the console as coordinates for a position, then use those to change screen coordinates of green box (div) and you will see that green box then gets placed in exact position where svg's rect left top corner is. Let me know if its unclear

Comment: added some description into the snippet, so that it was clearer on how conversion works.

Comment: I'm fairly certain this solution does not work except for in very specific circumstances. `getCTM()` returns the matrix for the element's transform within the svg's coordinate system, not the client coordinate system, for that you'll want `getScreenCTM()`. This solution will only work if the svg is in the top left corner of the root document, not sized, and with no transform.

Answer (score 27):

The code you included in your question converts screen coordinates to SVG coordinates.  To go the other way, you have to do the opposite of what that function does.

`getScreenCTM()` returns the matrix that you need to convert the coordinates. Notice that the code calls `inverse()`? That is inverting the matrix so it does the conversion in the other direction.

So all you need to do is remove the `inverse()` call from that code.

```js
var svg = document.getElementById("mysvg");

function screenToSVG(screenX, screenY) {
   var p = svg.createSVGPoint()
    p.x = screenX
    p.y = screenY
    return p.matrixTransform(svg.getScreenCTM().inverse());
}

function SVGToScreen(svgX, svgY) {
   var p = svg.createSVGPoint()
    p.x = svgX
    p.y = svgY
    return p.matrixTransform(svg.getScreenCTM());
}


var  pt = screenToSVG(20, 30);
console.log("screenToSVG: ", pt);

var  pt = SVGToScreen(pt.x, pt.y);
console.log("SVGToScreen: ", pt);
```

```html
<svg id="mysvg" viewBox="42 100 36 40" width="100%">
</svg>
```

Comment: Heads up: getScreenCTM() currently doesn't account for ancestor transforms in Safari.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure why it hasn't been suggested before, but [`Element.getBoundingClientRect()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) should be enough:

```js
const {
  top,  // x position on viewport (window)
  left, // y position on viewport (window)
} = document.querySelector('rect').getBoundingClientRect()
```

I think other answers might be derived from a method promoted by Craig Buckler on [SitePoint](https://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-translate-from-dom-to-svg-coordinates-and-back-again/), where he explains using the SVGElement API (instead of getBoudingClientRect, from the - DOM - Element API) to convert DOM to SVG coordinates and vice-versa.

But **1.** only DOM coordinates are required here **2.** he claims that using getBoundingClientRect when transformations (via CSS or SVG) are applied will return incorrect values to translate to SVG coordinates, but the current specification for getBoundingClientRect takes those transformations into account.

> The getClientRects() method, when invoked, must return the result of the following algorithm: [...]
>
> If the element has an associated SVG layout box return a DOMRectList object containing a single DOMRect object that describes the bounding box of the element as defined by the SVG specification, applying the transforms that apply to the element and its ancestors.

**Specification:** https://drafts.csswg.org/cssom-view/#extension-to-the-element-interface

**Support:** https://caniuse.com/#feat=getboundingclientrect

Comment: Because this returns the bounding box? Might be useful in some cases, but it sounds like this question was more interested in converting a point. For instance if you have a bezier curve you can still compute where a point on that curve is.

Comment: Indeed; moreover, getScreenCTM appears _much_ faster for a coordinate conversion. However, Safari doesn't currently account for ancestor transforms, so under some circumstances, getBoundingClientRect appears to be the only way to get some kind of accurate conversion.

Comment: Er, getBoundingClientRect() also has a bug.

Answer (score 2):

**2020**

⚠️ **Safari** currently has several bugs that make this pretty difficult if you're working with SVGs (or SVG containers) that are transitioning, rotated, or scaled.

`getScreenCTM()` does not include ancestor scale and rotation transforms in the returned matrix. (If your svgs are neither rotated or scaled, then this is the way to go though.)

However, if you know the ancestor elements that are being scaled and/or rotated, and their transformation values, you can manually fix the matrix provided by `getScreenCTM()`. The workaround will look something like this:

```
let ctm = ele.getScreenCTM();

// -- adjust 
let ancestorScale = // track yourself or derive from window.getComputedStyle()
let ancestorRotation = // track yourself or derive from window.getComputedStyle()

ctm = ctm.scale(ancestorScale)
ctm = ctm.rotate(ancestorRotation)

// !! Note: avoid ctm.scaleSelf etc. On some systems the matrix is a true blue SVGMatrix (opposed to a DOMMatrix) and may not support these transform-in-place methods
// --

// repeat 'adjust' for each ancestor, in order from closest to furthest from ele. Mind the order of the scale/rotation transformations on each ancestor.
```

If you don't know the ancestors... the best I've come up with is a trek up the tree looking for transformations via getComputedStyle, which could be  incredibly slow depending on the depth of the tree...

`getBoundingClientRect()` may return incorrect values when transitioning. If you're not animating things but you *are* transforming things, then this may be the way to go, though I'm pretty sure it's notably less performant than getScreenCTM. Ideally, insert a very small element into the SVG such that its bounding rect will effectively be a point.

`window.getComputedStyles().transform` has the same issue as above.

Answer (score 1):

#### Playing with `innerWidth`, `screenX`, `clientX` etc...

I'm not sure about what you are searching for, but as you question is arround `screenX`, `screenY` and *SVG*, I would let you play with *snippet editor* and some little tries.

Note that *SVG bounding box* is fixed to `[0, 0, 500, 200]` and show with `width="100%" height="100%"`.

The last line of `tspan` with print `x` and `y` of pointer when circle is clicked.

```js
function test(e) {
   var sctm=new DOMMatrix();
   var invs=new DOMMatrix();
   sctm=e.target.getScreenCTM();
   invs=sctm.inverse();
   document.getElementById("txt1").innerHTML=
       sctm.a+", "+sctm.b+", "+sctm.c+", "+sctm.d+", "+sctm.e+", "+sctm.f;
   document.getElementById("txt2").innerHTML=
       invs.a+", "+invs.b+", "+invs.c+", "+invs.d+", "+invs.e+", "+invs.f;
   document.getElementById("txt3").innerHTML=
      e.screenX+", "+e.screenY+", "+e.clientX+", "+e.clientY;

   var vbox=document.getElementById("svg").getAttribute('viewBox').split(" ");
   var sx=1.0*innerWidth/(1.0*vbox[2]-1.0*vbox[0]);
   var sy=1.0*innerHeight/(1.0*vbox[3]-1.0*vbox[0]);
   var scale;
   if (sy>sx) scale=sx;else scale= sy;
   document.getElementById("txt4").innerHTML=
       e.clientX/scale+", "+e.clientY/scale;
}
```

```html
<svg id="svg" viewBox="0 0 500 200" width="100%" height="100%" >
  <circle cx="25" cy="25" r="15" onclick="javascript:test(evt);" />
  <text>
    <tspan x="10" y="60"  id="txt1">test</tspan>
    <tspan x="10" y="90"  id="txt2">test</tspan>
    <tspan x="10" y="120" id="txt3">test</tspan>
    <tspan x="10" y="150" id="txt4">test</tspan>
  </text>
</svg>
```