# Can not translate screen x,y coordinates to svg coordinates

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I am trying to translate the position taken from the click event to the position which should be attached to the element which I want to append to my `<svg>`. Every time I click I want to add an element in the same place where I have clicked, let's say for example circle. I have read that `point.matrixTransform(svgRoot.getScreenCTM().inverse());` should do the trick and translate screen coordinates to SVG coordinates, but in my case it seems not to work (coordinates are not translated at all). This issue appears only if I add **`viewBox`** attribute to my `<svg>`. I do not know what I am doing wrong here. Maybe this cannot work for my case and I need to do the conversion manually?

**Example:**

```js
const drawingArea = document.querySelector('#drawing-area');
drawingArea.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  const { left, top } = drawingArea.getBoundingClientRect();
  drawCircle({
    x: e.clientX - left,
    y: e.clientY - top});
});

const drawCircle = ({ x, y }, r = 10) => {
  const circle = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'circle');
  circle.setAttribute('cx', x.toString());
  circle.setAttribute('cy', y.toString());
  circle.setAttribute('r', r.toString());
  drawingArea.appendChild(circle);
}

const translateToSVGCoordinates = (x, y) => {
  const point = drawingArea.createSVGPoint();
  point.x = x;
  point.y = y;
  point.matrixTransform(drawingArea.getScreenCTM().inverse());
  return { x: point.x, y: point.y };
}
```

```css
body, html {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<svg id="drawing-area" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 1920 1080" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet"></svg>
```

> If I wasn't enough clear what result I am expecting, just remove **`viewBox`** attribute from `<svg>` element

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are making it overly complex, both with SVG code and Web Component code...

Try this JSWC JavaScript Web Component to add `<circle>` to an existing SVG on every click

```html
<svg-draw-board></svg-draw-board>
<style>
  svg-draw-board {
    width      : 100vw;
    height     : 180px;
    display    : inline-block;
    background : pink;
    cursor     : pointer;
  }
</style>
<script>
customElements.define('svg-draw-board', class extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super()
       .attachShadow({mode:'open'})
       .innerHTML = `<svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 800 800"></svg>`;
    this.svg = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('svg');
    this.svg.onclick = (evt) => { // convert clientXY to SVG XY
      let CTM = this.svg.getScreenCTM();
      let x = (evt.clientX - CTM.e) / CTM.a;
      let y = (evt.clientY - CTM.f) / CTM.d;
      this.drawCircle( x, y , evt.ctrlKey ? 50 : 30 );
    };
  }
  drawCircle(cx, cy, r, fill = 'red') {
    this.svg.append( this.createSVGElement('circle', { cx, cy, r, fill }) );
  }
  createSVGElement( tag, attrs={} ) {
    const el = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg',tag);
    Object.entries(attrs).map(([name, val]) => el.setAttribute(name, val));
    return el;
  }
});
</script>
```

Comment: That works. Thank you. I will read more about this `getScreenCTM` I think I don't understand how it works

Comment: Alas there is no MDN documentation; you learn this from StackOverflow and blogs

Comment: ohhh I see, can you give me any reliable source from which I can learn more about this? (I am new in SVG world)

Comment: The 3 ``let`` lines is all code you need. **getScreenCTM( )** returns a DOMatrix (but you don't have to learn that) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMMatrix

Comment: thanks, a new tip ...  https://caniuse.com/?search=getScreenCTM  and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/samples/hh535760(v=vs.85)?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Comment: Yes, available in all browsers, and the latter link is for people who like Math and want to understand HOW Matrix transformations work

Answer (score 0):

The mentioned method `point.matrixTransform(svgRoot.getScreenCTM().inverse())"` works pretty well to translate Screen coordinates to SVG.

But **you haven't applied it anywhere in your script.**

In the following example, mouse coordinates are translated by receiving the event's properties and returning it to the `translateToSVGCoordinates()` helper function:

```
  drawCircle( translateToSVGCoordinates(drawingArea, e) );
```

I've added a 1 parameter to specify the parent svg as a reference for the matrix transformations.

```js
// parent svg
const drawingArea = document.querySelector('#drawing-area');
//const drawingArea = document.getElementById('drawing-area');
const ns = 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg';

drawingArea.addEventListener('click', e=> {
  drawCircle( translateToSVGCoordinates(drawingArea, e) );
});

const drawCircle = ({ x, y }, r = 10) => {
  const circle = document.createElementNS(ns, 'circle');
  circle.setAttribute('cx', x);
  circle.setAttribute('cy', y);
  circle.setAttribute('r', r);
  drawingArea.append(circle);
}

function translateToSVGCoordinates(svg, e){
    // get mouse coordinates
    let cursorPt = {x:e.clientX, y: e.clientY};
    
    // create point in SVG coordinate space 
    let point = svg.createSVGPoint();
    point.x = e.clientX;
    point.y = e.clientY;
  
    // translate to svg space coordinates
    let ctm = svg.getScreenCTM().inverse();
    point = point.matrixTransform(ctm);
    return point;
}
```

```css
svg{
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<svg id="drawing-area" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 1920 1080"></svg>
```

See also **Paul LeBeau's** Answer

["How to convert svg element coordinates to screen coordinates?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48343436/how-to-convert-svg-element-coordinates-to-screen-coordinates#48354404)

(describing both ways: SVG->screen and screen->SVG coordinates)

Your additional x/y offsets retrieved via `getBoundingClientRect()` are unnecessary.