# Eventlistener not working when mouse entering ID within svg file

Tags: javascript, html, svg, addeventlistener

I have created a simple code to mess around and learn with SVG files and eventlisteners.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>SVG Mouse Pointer Change</title>
<style>
    #svg5 {
        width: 50%; /* Adjust the width as needed */
        height: auto; /* Maintain aspect ratio */
    }
</style>
<script>
    window.onload = function() {
        var svgObject = document.getElementById('svg5');
        svgObject.addEventListener('load', function() {
            var svgDocument = svgObject.contentDocument;
            var rect = svgDocument.getElementById('rect237');

          // Function to change mouse pointer to crosshair
            function changeCursorToCrosshair() {
                console.log("Mouse entered rect237");
                document.body.style.cursor = 'crosshair';
            }

            // Function to change mouse pointer to default
            function changeCursorToDefault() {
                console.log("Mouse left rect237");
                document.body.style.cursor = 'default';
            }

            // Add event listener for mouse enter
            rect.addEventListener('mouseenter', function() {
                console.log("Mouse entered rect237");
                changeCursorToCrosshair();
            });

            // Add event listener for mouse leave
            rect.addEventListener('mouseleave', function() {
                console.log("Mouse left rect237");
                changeCursorToDefault();
            });

        });
    };
</script>
</head>
<body>

<object id="svg5" type="image/svg+xml" data="./img/simple_pitch.svg"></object>

</body>
</html>
```

However when testing the code nothing occurs. I have added some console logs but nothing is shown. I hope someone can let me know what I'm missing.

Thanks

Comment: I could be wrong, but it seems like if you can retrieve the element by id, then it's already been loaded, thus the load event won't execute again.

Comment: @mykaf That's not true. The element exists as soon as its HTML is parsed, but the contents are loaded asynchronously.

Comment: But you can confirm this by putting `console.log("load event occurred")` inside the event listener.

Comment: the code seems to skip the svgObject.addEventListener("load", function ()

Comment: what I would like to create ultimately is a webpage in which a user clicks inside the svg and the position is recorded. The idea is to create a event tracker for football games.

Answer (score 1):

Two things: Since the `<object>`'s data is set inline in the markup, the `window.load` event will wait for the `<object>`'s *load* event before it fires. So when you are in the `window.load` event handler, the `<object>`'s one has already fired and won't again until its `data` attribute changes.
This means that the `svgObject`'s *load* event won't fire and your callback won't be called.
So remove the line `svgObject.addEventListener('load', ...`  and call directly your code in the `window.onload` event handler.

Then, `document.body.style.cursor = 'crosshair';` will set the `cursor` of the **outer** HTML document's `<body>` tag, but the element you are hovering is the **inner** SVG document's `<rect>` element. Both documents are isolated and the `<object>`'s inner document will capture the pointer events, including the setting of the cursor.
If you want to change the cursor, you can set it to `svgDocument.documentElement.style.cursor = ...`.
<sub>(Obviously you could also have achieved the same with a simple `rect { cursor: crosshair }` CSS rule, but I get it's just a test to use events.)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Another alternactive, when you build DOM with a **native Web Component** you have full control on when an Element enters the DOM (the default `connectedCallback` fires)

You can create SVG upfront in *shadowDOM* (just those pesky SVG NameSpaces to be aware of)

You can then keep interaction closely tied to your Element without needing `addEventListener`

###### Creating one SVG element. with attributes and properties

Eventlisteners are set as properties

```js
        createElement("circle", {
          cx: ~~((Math.random() + 1) * 100) % 100 + "%",
          cy: ~~((Math.random() + 1) * 100) % 100 + "%",
          r: "2%",
          fill: "red",
          stroke: "blue"
        }, {
          onmouseenter: (evt) => this.mouseenter(evt),
          onmouseleave: (evt) => this.mouseleave(evt),
        }) // createElement
```

###### Complete Web Component

```js
const NS = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
const createElement = (tag, attrs = {}, props = {}) => {
  let el = document.createElementNS(NS, tag);
  Object.entries(attrs).map(([key, value]) => el.setAttributeNS(null, key, value));
  return Object.assign(el, props);
}
customElements.define("svg-object", class extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super()
      .attachShadow({ mode: "open"})
      .append(
        this.svg = createElement("svg", {
          viewBox: "0 0 400 400",
          style: "background:pink;height:160px"
        }, {
          onclick: (evt) => this.addCircle()
        }) //createElement
      ) //append
    this.addCircle();
    this.addCircle();
  } //costructor
  mouseenter(evt) {
    this.style.cursor = "crosshair";
    this.addCircle();
  }
  mouseleave(evt) {
    this.style.cursor = "default";
  }
  addCircle() {
    this.svg.append(
      createElement("circle", {
        cx: ~~((Math.random() + 1) * 50) % 100 + "%",
        cy: ~~((Math.random() + 1) * 50) % 100 *.5 + "%",
        r: "4%",
        fill: "red",
        stroke: "blue"
      }, {
        onmouseenter: (evt) => this.mouseenter(evt),
        onmouseleave: (evt) => this.mouseleave(evt),
      }) // createElement
    ) //append
  }
});
```

```html
<svg-object></svg-object>
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/WebComponents/53cmegLd/

For putting a circle at the *exact* click location see:
[Can not translate screen x,y coordinates to svg coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68316991/can-not-translate-screen-x-y-coordinates-to-svg-coordinates/68317546#68317546)
takes some extra line of CTM code

Comment: This answer doesn't seem to match the question at hand.

Comment: Sorry, instead of a ``<rect>`` I demoed a ``<circle>`` with **mouseenter** and **mouseleave** Events. Point [sic] is a Web Component is in full control when it "enters the DOM stage", no need for a ``onload`` Event, because you get all those goodies for free. You also then do not need a ``<object>`` to load SVG

Answer (score -1):

It is not clear from the question if you are running the HTML and SVG document from a web server. To make this work you need to run a web server. You cannot get access to the `contentDocument` if you just open the HTML file from the file system.

And in regards to the comments about the order of events. You must wait till the DOM is loaded before you can add an event listener to the object element. Using `window.onload` will wait till the document and all the resources has been loaded (so, after the resource in the object element is loaded), whereas `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', e => {})` will fire when the DOM is ready.

If the SVG `./img/simple_pitch.svg` has been cached by the browser it may not fire the load event. Therefor you can also test for the `readystate` of the `contentDocument`. If the readystate is complete, you know that the SVG has already been loaded.

Here is an example, where I changed the way that the crosshair style is set. The style of the cursor is not "tied to" the events of the mouse entering and leaving an element. If an element has a cursor style, then the cursor will change when the element is hovered. And then you can have the enter and leave events do something else (like, typically change the DOM).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', e => {
      let svgObject = document.querySelector('object');

      if (svgObject.contentDocument.readystate == 'complete') {
        loadSVGHandler(svgObject);
      } else {
        svgObject.addEventListener('load', e => loadSVGHandler(e.target));
      }
    });

    function loadSVGHandler(svgObject) {
      let svgDocument = svgObject.contentDocument;

      let rect = svgDocument.getElementById('rect237');
      rect.style.cursor = 'crosshair';
      rect.addEventListener('mouseenter', mouseEnterHandler);
      rect.addEventListener('mouseleave', mouseLeaveHandler);
    }

    function mouseEnterHandler(e) {
      console.log("Mouse entered " + e.target.id);
    }

    function mouseLeaveHandler(e) {
      console.log("Mouse left " + e.target.id);
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <object width="400" height="200" data="./img/simple_pitch.svg" type="image/svg+xml"></object>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You are using `DOMContentLoaded`, not window's load event. Both are different, window's load event **will wait** for the inline object has loaded, and beware, `DOMContentLoaded` may fail in case the file is cached: the load event could fire before the doc is entirely parsed. Also, the `<object>`'s load event will fire even if the resource is served from the file:// protocol, what happens in such a case is that the document is considered cross-origin and you can't access the `contentDocument` anymore.

Comment: @Kaiido I edited my answer in regard to your comments.