# Trying to create a styled tooltip for an inline SVG

Tags: javascript, css, svg, hover, tooltip

New to Js I am building an interactive pronunciation guide through an inline svg.

You can view it here: https://codepen.io/r-pg/pen/OJgoXWQ

I am currently trying to add basic styled tooltips which will display an associated sentence. I have bound its coordinates relative to the cursor position.

The js I am using for this is here:

```
function tooldef() {
  let t1 = document.querySelector('text[data-tooltip]');
  let t2 = document.querySelector('text:nth-of-type(2)');

  t1.addEventListener('onmousemove', showToolTip(evt));
  t2.addEventListener('onmousemove', showToolTip(evt));
}

function showToolTip(evt) {
  let t = evt.currentTarget;
  let phrase = t.getAttribute('data-tooltip');

  document.getElementById('tooltip').innerHTML = phrase;
  tooltip.style.display = "block";

  tooltip.style.left = evt.offsetX + 0 + 'px';
  tooltip.style.top = evt.offsetY + 0 + 'px';
  /* console.log(tooltip);*/
  console.log(evt.offsetX);
  console.log(evt.offsetY);
}

function hideToolTip(evt) {
  tooltip.style.display = "none";
}
```

This functions perfectly fine when loaded in through codepen or locally however when I apply this to Wordpress it pushes the tooltip far to the right ad I cannot Identify why. Is there an issue with the code or is this an internal problem within WP?

Comment: kind of hard to tell - but my guess might be that the transform/translate CSS for the tooltip that's specified in %'s might be the culprit. You're probably going to have to dynamically calculate a pixel equivalent based on whatever size the SVG ends up being - or move that transform directly into the SVG so it's in units that's relative to the SVG rather than the Body element.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Having checked the code I had actually commented out the translate CSS and the result was still the same. Using offsetX/Y sends it far to the left and pageX/Y and client X/Y send it to the right. I have it in such a way that I can retrieve the XY coordinates of the target however I cannot get the tooltip to display at that exact point, is there a method where I can set those relative to the SVG points? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your code for positioning the tooltip assumes a couple of things:

1. That your SVG is at 100% scale.
2. That your SVG is at the top left of the page

If you are embedding the SVG inside other content, then one or both of those will not be true any more.

You are attaching the `mousemove` events to SVG `<text>` elements. So the coordinates returned in the event will be in SVG coordinate space.  If the SVG is scaled to any size other than 1070 x 900, then your event coordinates won't match up with page coordinates.

If you are always displaying the SVG at 1070 x 900, then your fix might be as simple as just getting the page offset of the SVG, then add that X and Y position to the position returned in the event.

However if you are scaling the SVG, then you will need to convert the coordinates from SVG coordinates to page coordinates.  There are many other questions on here about that topic.  For example, this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48354404/1292848