# What is the replacement for the deprecated SVGPoint javascript API?

Tags: javascript, svg

I need to convert from a javascript click event to the coordinate space of an SVG element.  I am currently using techniques like https://stackoverflow.com/a/48354404/995935 , but https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGPoint says that SVGpoint is "no longer recommended" and "may cease to work at any time".

Unfortunately, it does not mention what API should be used to replace it.

How should I rewrite the code sample

```
function screenToSVG(screenX, screenY) {
   var p = svg.createSVGPoint()
    p.x = screenX
    p.y = screenY
    return p.matrixTransform(svg.getScreenCTM().inverse());
}
```

to avoid deprecated APIs?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMPoint, although SVGPoint is somewhat less deprecated than it used to be. DOMPoint works in Firefox, not sure about other UAs

Comment: There is so much code out there on the web that uses SVGPoint. I wouldn't worry about it disappearing anytime soon. It'll be around for years yet.

Answer (score 8):

Using [DOMPoint()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMPoint/DOMPoint). I was searching for this myself and it looks like it can replace SVGPoint 1:1. Here is an example:

```js
const svg = document.getElementById('svg01');
const print = document.getElementById('print');

const toSVGPoint = (svg, x, y) => {
  let p = new DOMPoint(x, y);
  return p.matrixTransform(svg.getScreenCTM().inverse());
};

svg.addEventListener('click', e => {
  let p = toSVGPoint(e.target, e.clientX, e.clientY);
  print.textContent = `x: ${p.x} - y: ${p.y}`;
});
```

```css
svg {
  border: thin solid black;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<p id="print">Position</p>
<svg id="svg01" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1000 500" width="400">
  <text font-size="100" x="50%" y="50%" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" pointer-event="none">Click me...</text>
</svg>
```

Comment: Any info on when Chromium is going to support this in **.isPointInFill**?  FireFox works fine. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGGeometryElement/isPointInFill