# SVGGeometryElement.isPointInFill() does not work with Chromium but works with Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I'm trying to work on a way to detect if a path of an svg file that is within a canvas is clicked on. My code works in Firefox however it does not work on Chromium browsers. I have surrounded the code with try and catch and I receive no errors on Firefox and everything works however on Chromium browsers I receive the error:

```
TypeError: Failed to execute 'isPointInFill' on 'SVGGeometryElement': parameter 1 is not of type 'SVGPoint'.
    at getIdOfElementAtPoint (main.js:39:27)
    at HTMLCanvasElement.<anonymous> (main.js:70:9)
```

However on the next piece of code no error is thrown.

This is my code:

```
function getIdOfElementAtPoint(event) {
    var paths = svg.getElementsByTagName("path");

    //loop through all the path element in svg
    for (var i = 0; i < paths.length; i++) {
        var path = paths[i];
        // Check if point (x, y) is inside the fill of the path
        
        let inFill = false;

        try {
            inFill = path.isPointInFill(new DOMPoint(event.clientX, event.clientY))
        } catch(error) {
            console.log(error)
            try {
                const point = svg.createSVGPoint();
                // Get the coordinates of the click
                point.x = event.clientX;
                point.y = event.clientY;
                inFill = path.isPointInFill(point)
            } catch(error) {
                console.log(error)
            }
        }

        if (inFill) {
            console.log("The point is inside the element with id: " + path.getAttribute("id"));
            return path.getAttribute("id"); 
        } 
    }
    console.log("The point is outside of any element.");
}
```

Comment: On Firefox at least you don't even need DOMPoint. `path.isPointInFill({x: event.clientX, y: event.clientY})` will work just fine.

Comment: @RobertLongson Hi again, yes, that's very interesting.

Comment: But for Chromium, [this bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=835431) is your problem.

Comment: @RobertLongson Theoretically this shouldn't matter as I still have the SVGPoint as a backup though right?

Comment: Any reason for not using [document.elementsFromPoint()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/elementsFromPoint) and finding the first <path/> from there? (That may not be exactly the same as this would be based on the pointer-events rules, and so would probably also includes the stroke, but maybe that's actually even better for you?) https://jsfiddle.net/zvLty0qe

Comment: I am unable to use elementsFromPoint(). And SVGPoint does not work on Chromium so I'm trying to find a solution.

Comment: To clarify, by "does not work on Chromium", I mean that I cannot get it to work on Chromium.

Comment: "I am unable to use elementsFromPoint()." Could you clarify why?

Comment: @Kaiido Because I am getting a location from an svg file that is not displayed.

Comment: But... `isPointInFill` is also supposed to require the element to be connected to work. It uses the same hit-testing rules, i.e it checks the computed value of `pointer-events`, which, assuming `"auto"`, checks whether the `visiblePainted` area is under the coords. With detached elements (or `display: none`/`visibility: hidden`), there is no `visiblePainted` area, and this method should always return false. Chrome [does that](https://jsfiddle.net/xw4z3qsm/), Firefox seems buggy here. (Note that the specs explicitly ask that the `visibility` property be set to `visible` to perform the check).

Comment: @Kaiido I have a XMLDocument stored in a variable. It is not visible to anyone. I'm not sure if I understand you correctly, are you saying that Chrome does not seem to work because it is not visible?

Comment: I am saying that `isPointInFill` requires the element to be attached to work. However your code should indeed bot throw an uncaught error, it should just always return nothing, because isPointInFill should always return false.

Comment: Hmm actually there are some conflicting statements between mdn and SVG2 specs, per SVG2 specs CSS rules other than `fill-rule` shouldn't matter, but if the element is not rendered an `InvalidStateError` must be thrown. Still not what you claim to get though.

Comment: @Kaiido Do you know of a way I can do something similar to isPointInFill that works with Chrome?

Comment: Append your SVG in a document so that it can have a correct computed box model. What Firefox does is kind of weird to be honest. Something like `<path style="d:M0,0..."/>` will not return the same depending on if the element is displayed or not. So if you wish to  check if a point is in a path, you'd need to determine how this path will really be rendered.

Comment: @Kaiido The problem is that i cannot have the svg file in a html document as I'm storing the html in a xml file stored as a variable in javascript.

Comment: Where is your js being executed? You have a document somewhere that has access to a CSS engine?

Comment: @Kaiido My js is being referenced by a html document and it is being run in a browser.

Comment: So you can append your SVG in a document.

Answer (score 1):

As commented by @Kaiido:
[`document.elementsFromPoint()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/elementsFromPoint) or
[`document.elementFromPoint()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/elementFromPoint)
are probably the better options to get SVG elements at certain cursor positions.

However you address several issues:

1. browser support for `DOMPoint()` used for SVG methods (firefox vs. chromium vs. webkit)
2. translation between HTML DOM coordinates (e.g. via mouse inputs) to SVG user units
3. retrieving all underlying elements at certain coordinates

##### Example snippet

```js
/**
 * static example: is #circleInside within #circle2
 */
let isInfill = false;
let p1 = { x: circleInside.cx.baseVal.value, y: circleInside.cy.baseVal.value };
let inFill1 = isPointInFill1(circle2, p1);
if (inFill1) {
  circleInside.setAttribute("fill", "green");
}


function isPointInFill1(el, p) {
  let log = [];
  let point;
  try {
    point = new DOMPoint(p.x, p.y);
    el.isPointInFill(point);
    log.push("DOMPoint");
  } catch {
    let svg = el.nearestViewportElement;
    point = svg.createSVGPoint();
    [point.x, point.y] = [p.x, p.y];
    log.push("SVGPoint");
  }
  console.log(log.join(" "));
  let inFill = el.isPointInFill(point);
  return inFill;
}

document.addEventListener("mousemove", (e) => {
  let cursorPos = { x: e.clientX, y: e.clientY };

  // move svg cursor
  let svgCursor = screenToSVG(svg, cursorPos);
  cursor.setAttribute("cx", svgCursor.x);
  cursor.setAttribute("cy", svgCursor.y);

  /**
   * pretty nuts:
   * we're just testing the reversal of svg units to HTML DOM units
   * just use the initial: e.clientX,  e.clientY
   */
  // move html cursor
  let domCursorPos = SVGToScreen(svg, svgCursor);
  cursorDOM.style.left = domCursorPos.x + "px";
  cursorDOM.style.top = domCursorPos.y + "px";

  // highlight

  let elsInPoint = document.elementsFromPoint(cursorPos.x, cursorPos.y);
  let log = ['elementsFromPoint: '];
  elsInPoint.forEach((el) => {
    if (el instanceof SVGGeometryElement && el!==cursor) {
      log.push(el.id);
    }
  });
  result.textContent = log.join(" | ");
  
});

/**
 * helper function to translate between
 * svg and HTML DOM coordinates:
 * based on @Paul LeBeau's anser to
 * "How to convert svg element coordinates to screen coordinates?"
 * https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48343436/how-to-convert-svg-element-coordinates-to-screen-coordinates/48354404#48354404
 */
function screenToSVG(svg, p) {
  let pSvg = svg.createSVGPoint();
  pSvg.x = p.x;
  pSvg.y = p.y;
  return pSvg.matrixTransform(svg.getScreenCTM().inverse());
}

function SVGToScreen(svg, pSvg) {
  let p = svg.createSVGPoint();
  p.x = pSvg.x;
  p.y = pSvg.y;
  return p.matrixTransform(svg.getScreenCTM());
}
```

```css
body{
  margin: 0em
}


svg{
  width:25%;
  border:1px solid #ccc
}

.highlight{
  opacity:0.5
}


.cursorDOM{
  display:block;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  margin-left:-0.5em;
  margin-top:-0.5em;
  font-size:2em;
  width:1em;
  height:1em;
  outline: 1px solid green;
  border-radius:50%;
  pointer-events:none;
}
```

```html
<p id="result"></p>
<p id="resultNext"></p>
<div id="cursorDOM" class="cursorDOM"></div>

<svg id="svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
  <rect id="rectBg" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="#eee" />
  <circle id="circle0" cx="75" cy="50" r="66" fill="#ccc" />
  <circle id="circle1" cx="75" cy="50" r="50" fill="#999" />
  <circle id="circle2" cx="75" cy="50" r="33" />
  <circle id="circleInside" cx="95" cy="50" r="5" fill="red" />
  <circle id="cursor" cx="0" cy="0" r="2" fill="red" />
</svg>
```

#### 1. `DOMPoint()` or `createSVGPoint()` for `pointInFill()`?

You're right: [`DOMPoint()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMPoint/DOMPoint) is currently **(as of 2023)**  not supported by chromium (blink) for some svg related methods.
[`createSVGPoint()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGPoint) works well in chromium as well as in firefox – although it's classified as deprecated.

Quite likely chromium will catch up to firefox.

But [`isPointInFill()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGGeometryElement/isPointInFill) or [`isPointInStroke()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGGeometryElement/isPointInStroke) are used for checking point intersection for single elements.

##### 2. Translate coordinates

Depending on your layout, you probably need to convert coordinates.
See @Paul LeBeau's answer: ["How to convert svg element coordinates to screen coordinates?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48343436/how-to-convert-svg-element-coordinates-to-screen-coordinates/48354404#48354404)

##### 3. Get all underlying elements

`document.elementsFromPoint()` is probably the best way to go.
However, this method will also return HTML DOM elements.
So you might need some filtering for svg geometry elements like so:

```
  let elsInPoint = document.elementsFromPoint(cursorPos.x, cursorPos.y);
  elsInPoint.forEach((el) => {
    if (el instanceof SVGGeometryElement) {
      console.log(el)
    }
  });
```

Comment: I am unable to use elementsFromPoint(). I have also tried using the SVGPoint() however that does not work on Chromium but works in firefox.