# Get the DWG mapped location from a SVG clicked location

Tags: javascript, svg, dwg

I use Aspose.CAD to convert a DWG file to a SVG file, so we can present SVG on a web page.

When a user clicks on the SVG, I can get a location of the SVG.

My question is how to get the mapped location of the original DWG from the location of the SVG?

Comment: Please add a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Provided the DWG coordinates were translated without any scaling to SVG units, you probably just need to convert click/pointer event based screen coordinates to user units as explained here ["How to convert svg element coordinates to screen coordinates?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48343436/how-to-convert-svg-element-coordinates-to-screen-coordinates#48354404)