# How can I keep the character on the screen when I scroll and still have it move along the path?

Tags: javascript, html, css

**This is my question**.

Please help me calculate the scrollProgress so that my pathIcon always stays within the screen when scrolling. Or if you have any other ideas, please let me know.

**Here is my code :**

```js
  pathIcon.style.offsetPath = `path('${Path_440.getAttribute("d")}')`;
      const pathLength = Path_440.getTotalLength();

      function clamp(min, val, max) {
        return Math.min(Math.max(min, val), max);
      }

      function updatePath() {
        const docElt = document.documentElement;
        const pathBox = theFill.getBoundingClientRect();

        // calculates scroll progress based on viewport progress
        const scrollProgress = clamp(
          0,
          -pathBox.y / (pathBox.height - docElt.clientHeight),
          1
        );

        pathIcon.style.offsetDistance = `${scrollProgress * 100}%`;

        // These lines fill in the dashes as you scroll down.
        const drawLength = pathLength * scrollProgress;
        const rest = pathLength - drawLength;
        theFill.style.strokeDasharray = `${drawLength}px ${rest}px`;
      }

      updatePath();
      window.addEventListener("scroll", () => updatePath());
```

```css
 body {
        height: 500vh;
        background: #f1f1f1;
      }
      .container {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
      }
      #pathIcon {
        position: absolute;
        inset: 0;
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        offset-rotate: 0rad;
      }
      .middlePath {
        position: absolute;
      }
      .crossLine {
        position: absolute;
      }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div style="height: 175px"></div>
    <div class="container">
      <div style="position: relative">
        <img
          class="crossLine"
          src="/public/pngegg.png"
          width="580"
          height="1500"
          alt=""
        />
        <svg
          width="540"
          height="2990"
          viewBox="0 0 540 2990"
          fill="none"
          xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
          class="middlePath"
        >
          <defs>
            <path
              id="Path_440"
              d="M253.744 2C253.744 2 8.36236 68.4995 17.2435 261C26.1246 453.5 380.243 311.5 380.243 531C380.243 750.5 15.2436 631.5 2.24357 826C-10.7564 1020.5 500.798 1091 535.244 1258.5C569.689 1426 296.243 1473 279.744 1460.5"
              stroke="#F39029"
              stroke-width="4"
            />
          </defs>
          <use href="#Path_440" stroke-dasharray="20 10" />
          <use id="theFill" href="#Path_440" />
        </svg>
        <svg
          id="pathIcon"
          viewBox="0 0 100 191"
          fill="none"
          xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
          xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
        >
          <rect width="100" height="191" fill="url(#pattern0)" />
          <defs>
            <pattern
              id="pattern0"
              patternContentUnits="objectBoundingBox"
              width="1"
              height="1"
            >
              <use
                xlink:href="#image0_126_965"
                transform="matrix(0.00376726 0 0 0.00197239 -0.00104536 0)"
              />
            </pattern>
            <image
              id="image0_126_965"
              width="266"
              height="507"
              xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUh"
            />
          </defs>
        </svg>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

It looks fine at first glance, but when I scroll, the pathIcon moves **too fast** and sometimes **goes off-screen**. I want it to **slow down** or **stay fixed** in the middle of the screen but **still move to the path**. This would make it smoother and give a better overview of the path.

Here is the current state and my desired outcome.
Please help me. Thank you for all your responses

Comment: Could you use StackOverflow's "JavaScript/HTML/CSS snippet" feature if possible? It's the 7th option in the editing bar. It makes a "Run code snippet" button, by which we can easily view what your code currently does.

Comment: This sounds a simple `position: fixed` would do the job, but as mentioned above, a working snippet would make it much easier to tell.

Comment: @lchristmann sorry about that, I have just finished editing, can you please review it for me?

Comment: @DBS I tried setting that attribute `position: fixed` on the pathIcon but it wasn't effective

Comment: @lchristmann 
It looks fine at first glance, but when I scroll, the pathIcon moves too fast and sometimes goes off-screen. I want it to slow down or stay fixed in the middle of the screen. This would make it smoother and give a better overview of the path.

Comment: Have a look at this answer ["Move an element along the svg path while placing it in center viewport"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77774355/move-an-element-along-the-svg-path-while-placing-it-in-center-viewport/77784141#77784141). Seems like the OP even used the same template code as you.

Comment: @herrstrietzel I've been searching for a long time and couldn't find it, you're really amazing. Thank you so much, this is exactly what I've been looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You need to adjust the calculation of the scroll progress and the position of the `pathIcon`. Try this:

```
const pathIcon = document.getElementById("pathIcon");
const Path_440 = document.getElementById("Path_440");
const theFill = document.getElementById("theFill");

pathIcon.style.offsetPath = `path('${Path_440.getAttribute("d")}')`;
const pathLength = Path_440.getTotalLength();

function clamp(min, val, max) {
  return Math.min(Math.max(min, val), max);
}

function updatePath() {
  const docElt = document.documentElement;
  const scrollPosition = window.scrollY;
  const pathBox = theFill.getBoundingClientRect();

  // calculates scroll progress based on the scroll position
  const scrollProgress = clamp(
    0,
    scrollPosition / (pathBox.height - docElt.clientHeight),
    1
  );

  pathIcon.style.offsetDistance = `${scrollProgress * 100}%`;

  // These lines fill in the dashes as you scroll down.
  const drawLength = pathLength * scrollProgress;
  const rest = pathLength - drawLength;
  theFill.style.strokeDasharray = `${drawLength}px ${rest}px`;
}

updatePath();
window.addEventListener("scroll", () => updatePath());
```

Comment: I've tried your code snippet, but it's not effective. When I scroll, the pathIcon moves only after a delay. I know what I need is scrollProgress, but I don't know how to adjust it properly.

Comment: Okay, I've got you. Now try the edited code.

Comment: thank you, but your code snippet moves similarly to mine.