# Get SVG Path Point Position Relative to DOM (not parent SVG)

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, dom, anime.js

I am trying to do a motion path of an image, that will jump from 1 SVG to another, following all paths.
The image is a normal

What I want is to move the image to a specific point, on any svg I have in my document.
If I add my image inside a SVG (using svg image) and move it, it's easy, I just use:

```
var temp_point=temp_path.getPointAtLength(temp_distance);
$('.handz').css("transform","translateX("+temp_point.x+"px) translateY("+temp_point.y+"px) rotate("+deg+"deg)");
```

But since I want to have my image outside the svg, and have 1 single image, that can be moved to any point on any path, from any svg from my document, I can't seem to figure it out.

I tried using:

```
function getRelativeXY(x, y, svg, element){

  var xx=element.getBoundingClientRect().x+x;
  var yy=element.getBoundingClientRect().y+y;
  return {x:xx,y:yy}
}
```

But it does not give me the desired results, as it does not move precisely where it should move. I think (I am not sure) it has something to do if the original svg has scaling/transforms applied, or different view box details.

[image]

Comment: Have a look at ["How to convert svg element coordinates to screen coordinates?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48343436/how-to-convert-svg-element-coordinates-to-screen-coordinates#48354404)

Comment: @herrstrietzel it helped. I managed to simply use: p.matrixTransform(svg.getScreenCTM());  since p is getPointAtLength() and already returns a point from the svg. I combined this with window.pageXOffset/Y offset to get the result I wanted